# Proving a ring is commutative if it is additively cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

From Pinter's Abstract Algebra, Second Edition, Chapter 17, Section H:

> **6.** Let $A$ be any ring. Prove that if the additive group of $A$ is cyclic, then $A$ is a commutative ring.

My attempt:

Let $a,b,c\in A$ where $c$ additively generates $A$. And let $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a = mc$ and $b = nc$. Then

$$ab = (mc)(nc)= m(nc)c = (mn)c^2 = (nm)c^2 = n(cm)c = (nc)(mc) = ba$$

Therefore, since $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary elements of $A$, $A$ is a commutative ring.$\Box$

I feel like I am implicitly assuming that $A$ is commutative. But intuitively it should be the case that $rc = cr$ for $c\in A$ and $r\in \mathbb{N}$. Since $r$ is representing the number of times $c$ is added.

Comment: The equality $(mc)(nc)=(mn)c^2$ is true in any ring, for $m,n\in \Bbb Z$. No problem there.

Comment: @Arthur Great! If you want to post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equality $(mc)(nc)=(mn)c^2$ is true in any ring, for $m,n\in \Bbb Z$. No problem there.

If you really want to prove it, you can write it out and distribute:
$$
(c+c+\cdots+c)(c+c+\cdots+c)=c^2+c^2+\cdots+c^2
$$

Comment: beginner's doubt, general form of element in cyclic group with generator C is 'nC' , n∈Z(not n∈N) right?